# Metastock end of day data to Python

Tags: equities, python

I'm thinking of getting End of Day stock prices from Metastock, but was wondering if it would be possible to have Python to automatically extract the stock prices and store it in a SQL.

Would that be possible? To use Python to interact with Metastock and collect data?

Any other recommendations for End of Day stock prices? (Asian Equities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metastock uses a binary format that you would have to convert to text before exporting it to a SQL table. Also, there is no Python library that could extract data directly from Metastock's end-of-day servers.

You may consider **quandl** which allows Python developers to download pricing data as well as economic indicators. You can download CSV, JSON, or XML. If you use their Python library, you can easily retrieve data into a pandas DataFrame.

https://www.quandl.com/

Comment: Thanks!! It's slightly more expensive than Metastock though. But I think phasing the data would be much much much easier.

Comment: You might purchase the [DataLink](http://www.metastock.com/products/endofday/reutersdatalink/?overview#endofday) tool that allows a text-based MetStock file, but you lose straight through automation. Once you have the text file, it should not be difficult to import it into a database.

Comment: you mean to say that if I get the DataLink tool, I would still need to manually download all the text files for the ticker/counter, and then I would be able to import it into a database? So in your opinion, it would be easier to just use quandl?